# Sort contents of a property file in a Gradle task

Tags: sorting, groovy, gradle, properties-file

As part of building a number of projects, I would like to sort the contents in some property-files that are semi-generated but also checked in to source control. The generation/update step in Gradle leaves them in different order (Done in 3rd party plugin code, probably the changing ordering is due to using the Java `Properties` class internally).

What is the simplest way to sort the contents of a file in Gradle?

The files are not large, reading in the file into lines, sorting and writing out again to the same file should suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following piece of code should do the job:

```
new File('lol').with { it.text = it.readLines().findAll { it }.sort().join('\n') }
```

With gradle task it will be:

```
task sortLines << {
   new File('lol').with { it.text = it.readLines().findAll { it }.sort().join('\n') }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Note that I had to use projectDir as in `new File(project.projectDir, '.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs')....` when using this in a multi-project build set.